# Structured Streaming - Processing part of the stream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

Is it possible to process only a part of the `.readStream` data stream?

In my setup I want to:

1. Ingest the data from Data Lake using Autoloader into Bronze Layer table
2. `.readStream` data from the Bronze Layer table and `.writeStream` Silver Layer table

But part of the requirements is being able to process the data in isolated batches. So for example two batches are ingested from ADLS in different Workflow runs (possible simultaneously) and they should be loaded from Bronze to Silver table in separation.

The problem I'm having is making sure that `.readStream` and `.writeStream` commands in execution of one separate batch, don't read (and possibly filter through) the whole new appended data (from both batches) and checkpoint it, so it won't be available to read in 2nd batch `.readStream`.

Should each process have its own checkpoint? Or it can be filtered in some way, maybe using `foreachbatch`?